# Opening userforms from a userform over and over - causes object issues

Tags: excel, excel-2003, userform, vba

I currently have built a tool in Excel 2003 which displays a series of data entry forms. The client has requested that there be "Previous Form" and "Next Form" buttons on the forms.

The code used to move between the forms is as follows

```
Sub NextForm(strFormName As String)
    Dim intCurPos As Integer
    Dim strNewForm As String

    'Find out which form we are currently on from a list in a range
    intCurPos = WorksheetFunction.Match(strFormName, Range("SYS.formlist"), 0)
    If intCurPos = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("SYS.formlist")) Then
        'We want to use the first one
        intCurPos = 0
    End If

    'Get the name of the form to open
    strNewForm = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("SYS.formlist"), intCurPos + 1)
    'Load the form into the Userforms Collection
    Set newForm = VBA.UserForms.Add(strNewForm)
    'Show the form
    newForm.Show
End Sub
```

The issue I have is that after you do this 25 times (yeah I know) the system crashes. I realise that this is because everytime you get to the newForm.Show line above the code doesn't get to complete and so sits in memory.

Modeless forms would stop this issue but then the user could load other forms and do other things which would cause major issues.

Does anyone have any suggestions to help with this? Somehow to force code execution but not stop the modal ability of the form?

Long shot but appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have to have all the 25 forms open?  Have you tried unloading a Form and then open the next one?

Comment: Have you considered using the MultiPage control on your userform i.e. load one userform and the use Next and Back to cycle through tabs on the MultiPage...

Comment: @CaBieberach: Each form unloads before the next one is opened. However the code point at which processing stopped for Form 1 remains in memory, and so on for the other 24. It's only when the final form is closed that Excel goes back to run the code (which in this case is just an Exit Sub).

Comment: @Remnant: We were using that. We were going to have two forms (there are two sets of separate data) but there were too many controls for Excel to load the forms. One form was to have 161 fields x 10 controls. The other was 95 x 10 controls. Excel had a spit, so we split into five forms.

We actually use a multipage control on each of these forms. There are 32 pages in total across the five forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should change your approach.

I would suggest the following:

In the main module use a loop to cycle open the form and loop every time the user press the "Next Form" button.

```
'This sub in your main Module
sub ShowAndCyleForms
   Dim FormName As String
   Dim MyForm as Object
   Dim CloseForm as Boolean

   FormName = "frmMyForm"         

   do while CloseForm=False
      set MyForm = VBA.UserForms.Add(FormName)           
      MyForm.Show
      CloseForm=MyForm.CloseStatus
      FormName=MyForm.strNewForm
      Unload MyForm
      Set MyForm = Nothing
   loop 

end sub
```

In every form, declare:

```
Public CloseStatus as Boolean
Public strNewForm as String
```

In every "Next Form" button, put something like:

```
Private Sub btnNextForm_Click()
   CloseStatus=False
   strNewForm= NextForm(Me.Name)
   Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Modify your sub to be a function that delievers the next Form Name

```
Sub NextForm(strFormName As String)
   Dim intCurPos As Integer

   'Find out which form we are currently on from a list in a range
   intCurPos = WorksheetFunction.Match(strFormName, Range("SYS.formlist"), 0)
   If intCurPos = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("SYS.formlist")) Then
       'We want to use the first one
       intCurPos = 0
   End If

   'Get the name of the form to open
   NewForm = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("SYS.formlist"), intCurPos + 1)
   '
End Sub
```

You will also need to modify your O.K. to just hide the form instead of unloading it and setting the CloseStatus to true.

The idea is to control all your forms loading/unloading from outside the from in a single procedure.

Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: this looks like a great solution - have you tested it to see if memory is retained and if there is an upper limit on the looping process before it crashes?

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a great start. I'm going to do up a test case to see how it goes but I can't see a problem from an initial look.

Comment: Firstly, thanks again for this. I've put this into a test case and it works just as it should. Brilliant. A note for those who come to this later - in the btnNextForm_Click, the CloseStatus=True should be CloseStatus=False. You only want to set CloseStatus=True when you no longer wish to display any forms. Cheers :)

Comment: Nice to hear it helped.  I edited my post to reflect the CloseStatus=False.  Thanks for the feedback